# how can i check if the name exist in table

Tags: c#, sql

i am new in c# and i don't know more about it but i have task must to do .

the idea is add new employee and when the user click on add button it must check if the name exist on the employee table in database so if the name exist it will not be added on the table and if not exist will be added on the table .

so please can any one help me on it :(

this is what the page design will be like this pic :

[image]

i made the check by the stored procedure and i do not know if it correct and also have an error :

```
@F_name nvarchar(50),
@isExists bit output
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here

 set @isExists = 0
if exists (SELECT F_name FROM Employee WHERE F_name =@F_name)
begin
       set @isExists=1
END
GO
```

the error is :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CheckRecord, Line 22
>   Incorrect syntax near 'END'.

Comment: add one more "END" statement before "GO"

Comment: just make `Name` column unique key

Comment: r u using SQL Server??

Comment: Assuming F_Name, is first name not full name, I'd suggest using something else for your 'EXISTS' check, as first name wouldn't provide sufficient unique values. Use email address if it is available, failing that if you can't find another uniquely identifiable value, use a combination of first name and surname.

Comment: yes i use it and i make the ID column primary key

Comment: OK the idea is about check on the name i can make first name and last name but i don't know how i do it

Answer (score 2):

I'll suggest using this checks on code-behind. You can easily do it with LINQ:

```
using(DataContext db = new DataContext())
{
    var name = db.Employee.Where(n => n.F_name == YourNameFromTextBox).FistOrDefault();
    if(name == null)
    {
        // insert data
    }
    else
    {
        // record exist - throw error
    }
}
```

If you dont wanna use LINQ, just use ADO.NET to read/write/update from DB:

```
SqlConnection dbConnection;
dbConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE F_name=@F_name", dbConnection);
SqlParameter sqlParam = new SqlParameter("@F_name", F_name);
myCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlParam);

myCommand.Connection.Open();
SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

string name = "";

if (myReader.Read())
{
    name = myReader.GetString("F_name");
    // now you get 'name' from DB here, do your job
}
myReader.Close();
myCommand.Connection.Close();
```

Comment: Why `Where().FirstOrDefault()` when you don't need the value? Surely `Any()` would suffice.

Comment: Sure, using Any() is more sufficient, but in my example programmer can operate value if it's not null, to add it to exception msg for i.e.

Comment: AddBtn_Click() event handler. But before that, to use LINQ, you will need to map your DB data by adding 'Linq To SQL classes' (dbml) file.

Comment: is there another way without using LINQ ? cuz i dont know any thing about it

Comment: then it is a good time to learn something new! ;-)
here is a simple steb-by-step tutorial [link](http://codesamplez.com/database/linq-to-sql-c-sharp-tutorial)

Comment: i wanna other way without LINQ is there any way ?

Comment: updated answer above for you with another example using ADO.NET to directly connect to DB. please mark as answer if it helps.

Comment: i make it like ( your Update ) and i have another error :(

http://im34.gulfup.com/03J51.png

Comment: GetString() method expecting integer as a parameter. i think you can do this: change query to "SELECT F_name FROM..." and use GetString(0);

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Just added one more END Statement at the end

```
@F_name nvarchar(50),
@isExists bit output
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here

 set @isExists = 0
if exists (SELECT F_name FROM Employee WHERE F_name =@F_name)
  begin
       set @isExists=1
  END

END

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one `END` statement as every `BEGIN` statement should have `END` statement.

It would be:

```
@F_name nvarchar(50),
@isExists bit output
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here

    set @isExists = 0
    if exists (SELECT F_name FROM Employee WHERE F_name =@F_name)
    begin
       set @isExists=1
    END
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force the database to don't accept the duplication in field Employeename

or use the code

```
try
con.open
cmd.commandtext="select * from T1 where name = '" & varablename &"'"
reader=cmd.excutereader
if reader.read
msgbox"the emp. is alrady founded in the database"
exit sub
else
' do the insertion
end if
catch ex as exception
msgbox ex.massege
end try
```

Comment: i do not understand can u explain more please ?

Answer (score 0):

> This is how you can write your Stored Procedure. One of the many ways i would say.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_yourProcName
    @F_name nvarchar(50) 
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT F_name FROM Employee WHERE F_name = @F_name)
        BEGIN
          -- Your INSERT statement here
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
         -- Your UPDATE statement here
        END
END
```

> So if there is any F_Name it wont `INSERT`. If you want, you can set your `UPDATE` logic on the `ELSE` statement.

Comment: OK i write the insert statement but the update how can i do it ? what the condition will be ?  and what the idea of using update ? can i write message " the name is already exist " instead of update ?